# (C++) How to search strings and replace each occurrence of a double quote with 2 double quotes?

Tags: c++, string

could something like this work? I've looked at guides and they don't seem to work for replacing a single char with two or more chars.

```
  for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
       if(s[i] == '\"')
           s[i] = '\"\"';
  }
  cout << s;
```

Comment: Why don't you simply try?

Comment: Reminder:  use `''` for *single* characters.  Use `""` for multiple characters.  Also, you can't assign multiple characters to a single character slot.

Comment: You could search the [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) section of your favorite references to see if there are any *methods* to help you *insert* characters into a *string*.

Comment: try to write the result into a new string; probably easier.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will not perform as you expect.

You are telling `std::string` to assign a 2 character constant, `'\"\"'`, into a slot that holds a single character.

Search the [`basic_string` section](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) of your favorite C++ reference to find a *method* to *insert* a *string* or multiple characters into a string.

**Edit 1 - Example**

```
std::string::size_type position = 0;
position = s.find('"');
while (position != std::string::npos)
{
  s.insert(position, "\"");
  position += 2;
  position = s.find('"');
}
```